# Countifs in quick sight

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I need help to for using countif in QuickSight.

eg: we have:

```
    name    id Location
    karthik 1   India
    harsha. 2   UK
    karthik 3   India
    Vikram  4   USA
    karthik 5   USA
```

I want the syntax in QuickSight for counting the number of records karthik with location Inida has in the above. Example answer is 2.

Please help with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can count using this syntax

`countIf(dimension or measure, condition)`

In your case.
`countif(name, {name} = 'karthik' AND {Location}= 'India' )`